# active record error in Ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am having trouble in rails, I have just installed it but when I update after updating mysql settings and running 
       `rake db:create` 
and then

```
rails server
```

It started server and then when I tried viewing it via browser there errors saying active record  connection not established error in strange way. I am new to both ruby and rails so that's why not understanding by debugging info. I assume that there is some thing wrong in MySQL configuration. I am using it on windows and using railsinstaller and using MySQL that came with XAMPP.

So can anyone tell that what is wrong with it and how can it be solved? Or is it better to use Linux for RoR? I do many things on windows thats why if there will be some solution at windows then that would be helpeful.

thanks for your time, following is attached output image.[image]

I also observed that rake db:create command is not creating db, I had to do this manually. Following is my configurations for db:

```
adapter:mysql2
host:localhost
encoding:utf8
database:kaasib_new
pool:5
username:root
password:~
```

So is this fine? I don't have password on local machine db and do I need to mention 3306 for mysql in it?

Comment: You should post your actual error output.

Comment: It would help us when you post these "very strange tihings".

Comment: more clarification and output added

Comment: You can get this running on Windows, but the answer to this: "Or is it better to use Linux for RoR?" is "yes" 1000 times over.

Comment: I think this thing is with all Python and PHP too to that they will run better on linux, @jdl what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try:

1. If the tilde character in the password field above is a typo, ok,
   but there shouldn't be anything there.
2. Not sure if it's a function
   of posting here, but Whitespace matters in YAML files. It should be
   set up with indents like below (socket is optional):

.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: it says un initialized constant Mysql2

Comment: it sounds like you need to make sure you have the mysql2 gem installed and not the mysql gem - ensure it's in your gemfile, and run bundle install

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Gemfile` from your project.
2. add line => `gem 'mysql2'`
3. run command => `bundle update`
4. `restart` your server.